# PostgreSQL datatype ROW?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I attempt to create a table with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE Client(ncli char(10) not null primary key,
                    nom char(32) not null,
                    adress row(rue char(30),
                    localite char(60)),
                    cat char(2));
```

I get an error saying :

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "row"

Why do I get the error, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I am not aware of that syntax in Postgres.  You should probably just create a separate `adresses` table.

Comment: Where in the [documentation of the create table statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) did you find that syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row when you insert some values but I think when you create the table, you need to create a new type :

```
 CREATE TYPE myAdress AS (
       rue char(30),
       localite char(60)
    );
```

Then use it to create your table :

```
CREATE TABLE Client(ncli char(10) not null primary key,
                    nom char(32) not null,
                    adress myAdress,
                    cat char(2));
```

Here is the doc, if you want to learn more : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rowtypes.html

Comment: Thank you i will try it.